# Is there a way to @Import configuration and override the behavior of one of the bean?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, abstract

I'm trying to create @Configuration class which will be @Import in different run time (in my project).
The configuration will create instance and I want for every run time to let him to do something else (like abstract behavior).

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {
   @Bean
   public SomeInstace getInstance {
       doSomething();
       return new SomeInstance()
   }

   public abstract void doSomething();
}

//run time configuration class
@Import({ConfigurationClass.class})
@Configuration
public class RunTimeConfiguration{

   @Override
   public void doSomething(){
      System.out.println("Do somthething else");
   }
}
```